# SQL Server convert datetime to int in query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a field that contains time in seconds after midnight, however SQL Server will only display it as `datetime yyyy-mm-dd hh.ss.xxx`. I am trying to query this and convert the data to seconds after midnight, the way it should be, e.g. `01:00` would be `3600`.

I have tried `SELECT CONVERT(int, timefield)` but the result is a column named (No column name) and values are -1 or -2.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function DATEDIFF:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, '12:00:00')
```

From http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35057980/mssql-timetosec.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I had to change the startdate from 0 to the one it specified but then it worked perfectly.

Comment: Lol well thats what i get for trying to make it better : ) I'll edit the post.

Comment: Also if this fixes your problem, you may want to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this

```
  SELECT [Total Seconds] = 
  (DATEPART(hh, GETDATE()) * 3600) + 
  (DATEPART(mi, GETDATE()) * 60) + DATEPART(ss, GETDATE())
```

Hope my answer help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but at this point I am not clear on how to use this.

Comment: Replace GETDATE() with your database column it will work perfectly :)

Comment: Works now - thanks a lot! Sorry if that was somewhat of a greenhorn questions, but I have just (been forced) begun to work with sql