# count difference in seconds between values from table and some moment in time using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

How to find difference in seconds betweem chosen moment and values from table using PostgreSQL?
For example chosen moment is '2003-05-21' and table look like

```
TABLE
Name        Date_of_Birth
Charles     2007-12-12
Matti       2003-09-20
Kath        2009-11-09
```

I tried to use this
SELECT EXTRACT(SECONDS FROM TIMESTAMP '2013-05-21')-EXTRACT(SECONDS FROM TIMESTAMP (SELECT Date_of_Birth FROM TABLE);

How to find how many second has gone from date of birth to the moment for every person from table? And results should be represented as table
Forgive me if my question is not understantable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server convert datetime to int in query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505644/sql-server-convert-datetime-to-int-in-query)

Comment: Wat? it's different, there required to use arguments from table

Comment: @SaggingRufus: an question for SQL Server can hardly be a duplicate for a question about Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract the `epoch` from the difference:

```
select extract(epoch from timestamp '2013-05-21' - date_of_birth) 
from the_table;
```

[From the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

> epoch 
>   [...] for interval values, the total number of seconds in the interval

Comment: Dat's great. Thanks for your help!